# How to pass certificate over rest request?

Tags: api, certificate, okta

I am building an application which registers an external IdP with Okta.
[Okta API doc.](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/idps#getting-started)

In order to do that, I need IdP certificate & other meta data from the user.

Thus workflow will look like this:

- User calls my endpoint and provides me with Idp details ( certificate
  & meta data )

  My application will then use the user provided Idp Details to call
  Okta and register the IdP.

However, how should user provide me with Idp ceritificate - encrypted or un-encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using https everything is already encrypted.  Assuming there is some sort of authentication to access your application, I would probably just proxy the parameters to the Okta API (maybe with some validation to avoid sending known bad requests).

Does that help?